# What is wrong with my proof of group order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism

Let $\phi: G\rightarrow H$ be an isomorphism of groups and let $a \in G$ be of order $n$. Show that the order of $\phi(a)$ is also $n$.

I was given this problem a week ago during a quiz and my following answer has been graded as "partially" correct lately. Despite checking my proof for a decent time, I could not figure out why my proof cannot be considered as "fully" correct so I have decided to ask it in here with my proof.

Proof:

$a\in G$ is order of $n$ $\Rightarrow$ $a^n=e_{g}$

$a^n=e_g \Rightarrow \phi(a^n)=e_{h}$

$\phi(a^n)=(\phi(a))^n \Rightarrow (\phi(a))^n=e_h$

Now assume that there exist a $k<n$ such that $(\phi(a))^k=e_h$ and $k$ is order of $\phi(a)$

$(\phi(a))^k=e_h \Rightarrow (\phi(a))^n=(\phi(a))^{mk+r}=(\phi(a))^r=e_h$

$(\phi(a))^r=\phi(a^r)=e_h \Rightarrow a^r \in \ker\phi$

$a^r \in \ker\phi \Rightarrow a^r=e_g$

$a^r=e_g$ and $r<k \Rightarrow a $ is order of $r$

This is obviously a contradiction hence order of $\phi(a)$ must be $n$

Comment: Notice your "proof" did not use the fact $\phi$ is an isomorphism, only the fact it is a homomorphism. What can go wrong? If $\phi$ is not an isomorphism, then $\phi$ can send $a$ of order $n$ to $\phi(a)$ of order strictly dividing $n$, in which case $r=0$, but then the fact $a^r=e_G$ and $r<k$ does not yield a contradiction.

Comment: Would be good: mention how to define $m$ and $r$. I **guess** $m, r ∈ ℕ$, $m \geq 1$, $k > r \geq 0$.

Comment: You seriously overcomplicated the second part of the proof by introducing the unnecessary $r$, and then forgot the case $r=0$. You could just use $\phi(a^k)=e_h$ to conclude.

Comment: @runway44 it used the isomorphism when he claims $\phi (k) = e_h \implies a^k = e_g$.

Comment: @runway44 The fact $\phi$ is an isomorphism was actually used in the last second line where I deduce $a^r \in Ker\phi \Rightarrow a^r=e_g$

Comment: @runway44 makes an excellent point worth remembering. Be wary if you find yourself not using the entire hypothesis to prove a claim!

Comment: But for a proper proof you have to mention why a conclusion holds. Before the second-two-last line only homomorphism properties were used, so that's something new worth mentioning.

Comment: Last line: it's not important that $r < k$ since we are talking about $a∈G$. It's important that $r < n$ (because $r < k < n$). And as @MichalAdamaszek mentions the case $r = 0$ is forgotten.

Comment: BTW, the simple way to prove it, once you've done the first part, is to say that you've proven that $ord(\phi(a))\leq ord(a)$. Then by symmetry $ord(a) \leq ord(\phi(a))$, so it follows that $ord(a) = ord(\phi(a))$. Also, missing the case that $r=0$ is a bit weird, as it's rather trivially true that $r=0$ (if $a^n=e$, then obviously $ord(a)|n$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, if $k$ divides $n$, you end up with $\big(\phi(a)\big)^0=e_h$, which is trivially true, because $b^0=e_h$ for all $b$

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Evaristos answer here the completion/correction:

Let $k = \operatorname{ord} φ(a)$. Since $e_h = φ(e_G) = φ(a^n) = φ(a)^n$, $n \geq k$.
$φ(a^k) = φ(a)^k = e_h$. Since $φ$ is bijective and $φ(e_h) = e_G$, we get $a^k = e_G$. Hence $n | k$ but with $k \leq n$ we have $n = k$.